# How to converted Row into Column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, common-table-expression

How to converted Row into Column in SQL Server.

I have single table have 3 column i want to converted into single row
Sample Code as below

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY ,
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO  #TABLE VALUES ('ABC','INDIA')
    SELECT *
    FROM #TABLE

ID | NAME |ADDRESS
1  | ABC  | INDIA
```

I want out like this

```
ID     |1
NAME   |ABC
ADDRESS|INDIA
```

I try to achieve using CTE & pivot hard luck

Answer (score 4):

Set up a *mockup* table with your values

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    [NAME] VARCHAR(10),
    [ADDRESS] VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO  @tbl VALUES ('ABC','INDIA')
                        ,('one','more')
```

--This approach uses `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES()` to create a derived resultset
--You need to know the column names in advance and you must cast them to a common type

```
SELECT A.*
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('ID',CAST(t.ID AS NVARCHAR(100)))
                  ,('NAME',CAST(t.[NAME] AS NVARCHAR(100)))
                  ,('ADDRESS',CAST(t.[ADDRESS] AS NVARCHAR(100)))) A(ColumnName,ColumnValue)
```

--This approach is fully generic and works with any set and type

```
SELECT AllCols.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnName
      ,AllCols.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnValue
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
) A(AsXml)
CROSS APPLY A.AsXml.nodes('/row/*') B(AllCols)
```

The idea behind is to read the select as XML and use the generic abilities of `XQuery`:

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <NAME>ABC</NAME>
  <ADDRESS>INDIA</ADDRESS>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <NAME>one</NAME>
  <ADDRESS>more</ADDRESS>
</row>
```

Comment: Thank for give solution.

Comment: @Syan Always glad to help! if this solved your issue, you might tick the acceptance check to close this. Happy Coding!